# Regex pattern reads correctly but doesn't produce desired result

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am testing the following regex:
`(?<=\d{3}).+(?!',')`
This at regex101 [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Rvk91A/1)

Test string:

```
187 SURNAME First Names                     7 Every Street, Welltown Racing Driver
```

The sequence I require is:

1. Begin after 3 digit numeral
2. Read all characters
3. Don't read the comma

In other words:

```
 SURNAME First Names                     7 Every Street
```

But as demo shows the negative lookahead to the comma has no bearing on the result. I can't see anything wrong with my lookarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.+` consumes everything.

So `(?!,)` is guaranteed to be true.

I'm not sure if using quotes is correct for whichever flavour of regex you are using. Bare comma seems more correct.

Try:

```
(?<=\d{3})[^,]+
```

Answer (score 2):

You could match the 3 digits, and make use of a capture group capturing any character except a comma.

```
\b\d{3}\b\s*([^,]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b\d{3}\b` Match 3 digits between word boundaries to prevent partial word matches
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `([^,]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars other than a comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tL0Sz9/1)